# Upload directly via camera on Microsoft Surface 2 (RT)

Tags: fine-uploader

According to [this blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/05/09/upload-directly-via-a-camera-on-mobile-devices/) FineUploader supports direct camera upload on the Microsoft Surface tablet. Which is great.

However, I have tested this on your Demo page and I am getting no camera option. Just the usual "This PC", "Sky Drive", "Network" etc options.

Can you please point me to a demo where I can see this working live (preferably), or alternatively some documentation that describes how to make it work specifically on the Surface?

If I can see this working, I'll buy a license.

Thank you.

Comment: Metro is the requirement, but ideally both. I have tested both and neither options works from the Demo page. Note that I am using a Surface 2 (RT / non-pro version).

Comment: It seems to work just fine with the original surface in metro mode.  We don't have an S2 to test with here, so if it isn't working in metro mode on the S2, I can't say why.  This is only possible in metro mode at the moment.  In metro mode on the original Surface, you can select the camera by exposing the dropdown on the top-left of the page.  The menu name/selection usually defaults to "Files", and is accessible once you invoke the file chooser.  Can you post a screenshot of the file chooser you are seeing?

Comment: @RayNicholus No such option on S2 im afraid. how bizarre.

Comment: @RayNicholus http://imgbox.com/zHvKsPN7
http://imgbox.com/MIqSJpOa

Comment: Are you certain that drop-down menu isn't scrollable?

Comment: Yes. It behaves like it is scrollable but no camera option in there. Just called my colleague who has a Surface 1 RT and it is not working on his device either. Perhaps a recent update to the Surface knocked out this functionality?

Comment: Perhaps.  I'll take another look.

Comment: Our Surface RT is all up-to-date, and we can access the camera after invoking the file chooser button.  I've reproduced by clicking on the "upload a file" button on the first demo at http://fineuploader.com/demos.html.

Comment: @RayNicholus Ray, any chance you could upload a screenshot of the option you get to access the camera?

Comment: Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/h8yxhms.png

Comment: @RayNicholus Hi Ray, we have now tested this on Surface 1, 2, RT and Pro versions and we are not seeing the same menu as you. I believe your device is still Windows RT 8.0 and has not yet been upgraded to 8.1. Can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: It looks like we may have 8.0.  Not sure exactly, as the system screen says "Windows RT".  If that's the case, please open up a bug report in the Github issue tracker.  We'll have to upgrade to 8.1 and look into this further.

Comment: Yes, its 8.0, otherwise it would say 8.1. And there you have it. Microsoft in their infinite wisdom have completely removed this capability with 8.1. I will open an issue as advised.

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully we can work around this somehow.